# WPF LINQ Glitch

Tags: wpf, linq

I have a WPF application that was using inline SQL, I converted the application to LINQ and it works fine on all PC's accept for one. The application loads fine, but the first time a method that contains LINQ is called the application stops working. There is no error and the cursor continues to spin. The only way to stop it is to close the application. I have tried uninstalling and re-installing the app as well as uninstalling and re-installing .net. All to no avail. Any advice anyone could give me would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Assuming that all the machines that work and don't have the same specs, I would suspect that you have a corrupted assembly on disk. I would run  a disk check utility to see what it reports.

Comment: It would also be good to know what the error is. Perhaps wrap the statements in question in a try/catch with a messagebox so you can see what the error is.

Comment: Check you are not losing exceptions, either because you are catching them without logging/reporting them or because you are not catching exception in threads. Also, if the configuration is incorrect, it could be attempting to reach the wrong sql-server and it can take some time before an error is reported especially if you have increased the connection timeout.